# Method not allowed on ajax request (keydown event active only while debugging)

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I have a very strange problem with an AJAX request.

The server `app.py`

```
#### app.py

from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


@app.route("/myajax", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mypostajaxreq():
    
    print(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form["name"]
        return " Hello " + name
    else:
        return "Just Hello"                
            

@app.route("/")
def index():
    
    return render_template("indexlistener.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The `indexlistener.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Practice AJAX</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/static/js/myajaxrequestlistener.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <label>Name:<input type="text" id="name" value="" /></label>
      <button type="button" id="btn-post">Click</button>


      <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `myajaxrequestlistener.js` file

```
function do_ajax ()
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            result.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }

    req.open('POST', '/myajax', true);
    req.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
    req.send("name=" + document.getElementById('name').value);
};



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    document.getElementById("btn-post").addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        do_ajax();

    })
})




document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event)
    {
        if(event.key === "Enter")
        {
            do_ajax();
        }

    })
})
```

This works all well when I click the button, as expected it fires the `mypostajaxreq` in the python code, however when I press `Enter` it returns `Error 405. Method not allowed`. It is unclear to me why it's happening, I checked with the debugger and I am entering the listener event to `keydown`, in fact, even weirder, the code works when I use the debugger but it doesn't when I press `Enter` directly. I suspect it's due to the listener but I don't understand why it shouldn't work. Besides I don't understand the logic of the error (`405`) I'm receiving: in my understanding this should happen only when the route on the server side doesn't accept the request method is called from, but here I accept both and besides I'm firing only POST requests from the webpage. I'm new to web programming, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try changing the button type to submit, in that case you won't need the button listener. And also can you remove the `method` and add the following line `onsubmit="do_ajax()"` on the form element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing enter in the only textbox in a form will submit the form, sending a POST to `/`  which is not an allowed method to that route.
You can attach a submit handler to the form instead of a keydown
Also, you don't have to use multiple `DOMContentLoaded` event handlers.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        do_ajax();
    });
    document.getElementById("btn-post").addEventListener("click", do_ajax);
});
```

Comment: There's only a small typo in the answer, you missed an `addEventListener` before `.("submit`